# Excel - COUNTIFS with multiple Date Range Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I'm trying to count the Total Number of Records Ordered Date 3rd-4th Quarter of year 1997 & 1998

Here is my attempt:

```
=COUNTIFS(database!I10:I2164,">=1/7/1997",database!I10:I2164,"<=31/12/1997",database!I10:I2164,">=1/7/1998",database!I10:I2164,"<=1/12/1998")
```

but it returns 0.

```
database!I10:I2164
```

is where the column of the date. Its sample value is 07/04/1998 but it is formatted as 07-Apr-1998.

Comment: A date can't be q3/q4 1997 _and_ q3/q4 1998

Comment: how do I write a correct formula?

Comment: Contifs( 1997 criteria ) + Countifs( 1998 criteria )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`COUNTIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) is doing a logical AND across the criteria and a data can't be in two years at once as @ChrisNeilen points out. See the quote from support.office.com below - my emphasis in the quote:

> The COUNTIFS function applies criteria to cells across multiple ranges and counts the number of times **all** criteria are met.

Your check needs a logical OR i.e.

> 7 <= month <= 12 ***and*** (year = 1997 ***or*** 1998)

So you sum two `COUNTIFS` formula to get that:

`=COUNTIFS(
  database!I10:I2164, ">=1/7/97", 
  database!I10:I2164, "<=31/12/97"
) 
+ 
COUNTIFS(
  database!I10:I2164, ">=1/7/98", 
  database!I10:I2164, "<=31/12/98"
)`

If you are worried about Excel not correctly matching values because of date formats etc then use a `SUMPRODUCT`:

`=SUMPRODUCT(
  --(MONTH(database!I10:I2164)>=7),
  --(MONTH(database!I10:I2164)<=12),
  --(YEAR(database!I10:I2164)>=1997),
  --(YEAR(database!I10:I2164)<=1998)
)`